# Assembly - put in buffer register value

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, masm32

My `eax` register has the following value

`EAX DDCCBEE6`

I want to put the value of `eax` to buffer so I can use it as it, I mean if I used `SetDlgItemText` it must set the text value of edit control to `eax` value which is `DDCCBEE6`

The value of `eax` is a result of math instructions

Comment: You can do it manually with [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756).  `sprintf` is slower but maybe easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wsprintf` for that purpose:

```
.data
format  db "%X",0

.data?
buffer  db 256 dup (?)

.code
invoke wsprintfA,ADDR buffer,ADDR format,eax
```

Note that there are safer alternatives to `wsprintf`, but I don't know if they can be found in the masm32 include files and import libraries.