# MIPS Assembly converting integer to binary and reading the number of 1's?

Tags: assembly, binary, mips

I am working on a program that takes an integer from the user and then outputs how many 1's there are in it's binary equivalent.  So first I believe I need to convert it to binary and then use a loop and check all 32 bits to find how many 1's there are.

I have been browsing around for hours and trying different things to first convert the integer to binary.  What's the best way to do this?  Is there a way to to read a register value in binary directly, or do I need to convert it first?  This is all the code I have so far.

```
  .data
EnterInteger: .asciiz "Enter an integer: "


.text
 # Print the first message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, EnterInteger
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter the first integer
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t0
 move $t0, $v0
```

Here is the code I have so far but it's not working.  When I input 4673 I should get "4", instead I only get "1"

```
    .data
Msg: .asciiz "Enter an integer: "



.text
 # Print the first message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Msg
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter the first integer
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t0
 move $t0, $v0

 addi $t3, $zero, 0

main:
 bgt $t3, 32, exit
 andi $t0, $v0, 1
 bne $t0, $zero, count 
 



count:
 addi $t3, $t3, 1
 addi, $t1, $zero, 1
 # Shift to the next bit and then go back to main
 srl $t0, $t0, 1
 j main
 
exit:

# Tell the interpreter to get read to print an integer
 li $v0, 1
 add $a0, $zero, $t1
 
 #Print the integer
 syscall
 
 # End the program
 li $v0, 10
 syscall
```

Comment: _"I believe I need to convert it to binary"_. No, you already have it in the correct form. The general-purpose registers each consist of 32 bits. Whether you wish to think of those bits as representing a decimal number, a binary number, or a UTF-16 character depends on the context in which the register is being used. But in the end it's just a group of bits.

Comment: Updated my question with what I have.  Still haven't quite figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael commented, **integers in registers are already in binary**.  A register is a group of 32 bits.

Crucially, **operations on registers** like `andi $t1, $v0, 1` and `srl $v0, $v0, 1` **work in binary**.  i.e. the resulting 0 or 1 from `and` is the value mod 2, and right-shift by 1 place divides by 2.

This is a consequence of MIPS being a *binary* computer, like every over real-world ISA you might learn assembly for.  Higher-level languages including C, Java, and Python that have `&` and `>>` operations also always guarantee that they work in binary.  (On a non-binary computer, e.g. ternary, implementing those semantics for `x & y` would involve converting to an array of base-2 digits and doing the logic manually, then converting back.)

If you want to work with other number bases, like base 10, you'd need to do actual division (MIPS `divu`) or remainder to remove or isolate the lowest base-10 digit.  Or if the base is a power of 2, like base 16, then shift by 4 bits, or AND with `0x0f` (take the low 4 bits, i.e. 0b1111).

---

Input / output in other bases involves converting (binary) integers from / to strings of ASCII digits representing digits in another base.  The MARS/SPIM read_int call (`syscall` with $v0 = 5) does that for you, like C library functions scanf or printf.  To do it manually, you do stuff like `total = total * 10 + digit`, where `digit` is something like `ascii_char - '0'`.  Or for output, repeated division / modulo by 10 to get the base-10 digits, starting with the lowest.

There are some MIPS Q&As about manually converting to/from strings, but not many because most students using MIPS are using MARS or SPIM with their toy system calls that do things normally done by a C library, or by hand. But IIRC there are some if you search.

ASCII decimal or hex strings are a *serialization format* for numbers, not how they exist inside computers (except as strings, not integers).

---

#### Popcount

Looping over the bits one at a time, extracting and adding the low bit, is a simple but often inefficient way to count the number of set bits.  Still, simple is good for a first attempt; the choice of `andi` and `srl` as examples earlier is a hint.

Some faster bithacks are shown on [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer) although for MIPS that means generating lots of separate 32-bit constants which cost 2 instructions each.  You could do two SWAR widening steps and then loop over groups of 4-bit sums, as a middle ground.

[Count bits 1 on an integer as fast as GCC __builtin__popcount(int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387998/count-bits-1-on-an-integer-as-fast-as-gcc-builtin-popcountint) shows a way where you count iterations of `n &= n-1` to [clear the lowest set bit](https://catonmat.net/low-level-bit-hacks), which is faster if there are only a few bits set, even if they're not near the bottom of the register.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  For so a simple top down approach I could use andi and srl?  Only been learning assembly a few weeks so it's still quite confusing.

Comment: @Java_Assembly55: Not "top down"; it's easiest to start with the least-significant bit first (the bottom bit), then right shift the integer by 1 to bring the next bit down to that position.  I wouldn't call that "bottom up", though, I'd call it "LSB first".

Comment: Okay I see.  But for andi I, it's defined as "The andi instruction does a bitwise AND of two 32-bit patterns".  If I just have one input from a user, shouldn't I be able to srl to check each bit and then ask if the bit is equal to $zero to figure out how many 1's it has?

Comment: @Java_Assembly55: `andi $tmp, $v0, 1` *is* how you check a single bit, by isolating it.  (zero-extending it into a 32-bit integer 0 or 1).  `do{ sum += v & 1; v >>=1; }while(v);`

Comment: Okay, so, I would do that and then loop it with srl and add 1 to another temp?

Comment: I just updated the question with the code I have.  Shouldn't this loop and shift for all 32 bits be working?