# nasm assembly: Can't find valid values for all labels after 1004 passes

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to write an x86 assembly code for NASM assembler, which will convert a hexadecimal number into a string and print it. For simplicity I have assumed that my hexadecimal number will only contain digits(eg. 0x1234). Here is the code:

**print_hex.asm**

```assembly
    [org 0x7c00]
    
    mov dx, 0x1234
    call print_hex
    
    jmp $
    
    print_hex:
        push bx
        push cx
        push dx
        push ax
    
        mov bx, HEX_STR
        mov cx, 0x000f
        mov ax, 0x0000  ; length counter
    
    loop: 
        push bx         ; save bx
        and cx, dx      ; 0xabcd & 0x000f
        add bx, 5       ; find position in the template
        sub bx, ax
        add [bx], cl 
        pop bx
        shr dx, 4       ; next digit
        mov cx, 0x000f
        inc ax          ; increment counter
        cmp ax, 4
        jl loop         ; loop through the digits
    
        pop ax
    
        call print_string
    
        pop dx
        pop cx
        pop bx
        ret
            
    
    %include "print_string.asm"
    
    HEX_STR:           ; template string
        db '0x0000', 0
    
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

**print_string.asm**

```assembly
    print_string:
        mov ah, 0x0e
        push bx
    
        loop:
            cmp BYTE [bx], 0
            je end
            mov al, [bx]
            int 0x10
            inc bx
            jmp loop
    
        end:
            pop bx
            ret
```

If I try to assemble/compile `print_hex.asm` with NASM, it gives following error:

> print_hex.asm:error: Can't find valid values for all labels after 1004 passes, giving up.
>
> print_hex.asm:error: Possible causes: recursive EQUs, macro abuse.

I have noticed if I don't use any labels(like loop label here) code works fine.

Comment: `loop` is a pretty bad label name to begin with since it's also the name of an instruction. But you could try making those labels local instead (i.e. `.loop:`)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know there is an instruction `loop`! Changing the name of the label works. Thanks!

Comment: Huh, I thought putting a colon on the line disambiguated it vs. an instruction. 
 So `loop:` is unambiguously a label.  Did you change it to `.loop` (a local label, i.e. shorthand for `print_hex.loop:`), or did you leave it with two definitions of the same non-local label, like `myloop:` and `myloop:`?

Comment: (`%include` works just like in C: the sources effectively become part of the same file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your actual problem is that you defined the label `loop:` twice.**
NASM 2.14.02 prints a nice error message:

```
$ nasm print_hex.asm 
print_string.asm:5: error: label `loop' inconsistently redefined
print_hex.asm:19: note: label `loop' originally defined here
```

The `%include` preprocessor directive works just like in C `#include`: the sources effectively become part of the same file, sharing the same namespace for symbols.

Presumably you have an older version of NASM that printed the insane and unhelpful error message.  IDK if the it's related to the fact that `loop` is also an instruction mnemonic.  It shouldn't be, but it's hard to imagine NASM having such an unhelpful handling of duplicate labels in any recent version.  That's a common enough mistake in hand-written asm, and that's what NASM is usually used on.  So perhaps NASM had a bug that snuck `loop` past the usual duplicate detection and got it to try and fail.

`loop:` disambiguates the line as definitely a label, not an instruction line for NASM.  (But not YASM: it won't let you use `loop:` as a label)

---

### Use local label names

`.loop:` is scoped to the previous non-local label.  So it's like shorthand for `print_hex.loop` and `print_string.loop` in both the declaration and use.

https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.9

---

#### Code review

BTW, your code is pretty bloated.  You don't need to save/restore every register in every function; just let them clobber regs.

Also, you can convert int->hex more efficiently, and without needing a template to add into.  (The initial `0x` is handy but the rest you can calculate in regs).  Also, I don't think your code handles the `0..9` vs. `a..f` split: those ranges of ASCII character codes are unfortunately not adjacent to each other.

See [How to convert a number to hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-number-to-hex) for a simple 32-bit version you can easily port to 16-bit, with a lookup table or with a conditional to handle the 0..9 vs. a..f.  See also https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/193842/1 for a simple version with a conditional branch.  (A later version saves even more code size using DAS).

Use small constants as immediate operands, like `and al, 0xf`, instead of putting them into CX.  Decrement a pointer from the end of the buffer if you want, or with hex you can use a rotate to get nibbles from the top and generate in printing order.