# Confused with AX and AL registers

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, cpu-registers

So, I'm figuring out Assembly by writing a function that prints a hexadecimal number.
How function works: in a loop, it gets the last digit of a number, converts it to a char, and replaces char at `HEX_OUT` string (`HEX_OUT: DB "0x0000", 0`, so the function is going to rewrite each char to make the corresponding number), and then repeat it until the number will be mapped to the `HEX_OUT` string, and then it prints it.

But there's a problem with registers that I don't understand.
The problem is that when I put some value into `ax` register (say, `6`), and then place the value of `ax` into `bx` register (`mov [bx], ax`), at the end of the day I get `0x1` printed on my screen, but if I change the instruction to `mov [bx], al`, I get `0x1fb6` (assuming that the number to be printed is 0x1fb6, it's correct result).

As far as I know about registers, since I placed `6` in `ax`, `al` register should be equal to the value of `ax`.

Please, look at the comment line with `[HERE]`, this where the problem is.

```
; HEX_OUT ("0x0000") is stored in bx
; hexadecimal number to be printed (0x1fb6) is stored in dx

print_hex:
    pusha
    mov cx, 0                   ; cx = counter

loop1:
    cmp cx, 4                   ; if counter < 4
    jl print                    ; jump to print
    jmp end                     ; else jump to end

print:
    mov ax, dx                  ; ax = 0x1fb6
    and ax, 0x000f              ; ax = 6
    cmp ax, 9                   ; if ax > 9
    jg num_to_abc               ; make a letter out of char (because hexadecimal)
    jmp next                    ; jump to next

num_to_abc:
    add ax, 39
    jmp next

next:
    add ax, '0'                 ; make a char out of num
    mov bx, HEX_OUT + 5         ; bx now points to last char of string
    sub bx, cx                  ; bx = bx - counter
    mov [bx], al                ; [HERE] al is currently 54 (6 + '0'). But why al works properly, but ax doesn't?
    ror dx, 4                   ; put last digit at the beginning (before: 0x1fb6, after: 0x61fb)
    inc cx                      ; counter++
    jmp loop1                   ; jump back to loop

end:
    mov bx, HEX_OUT             ; some code
    call print_string
    popa
    ret
```

print_string function (I don't think there's any problems with it):

```
print_string:       
pusha               
mov ah, 0x0e        
loop:               
    mov al, [bx]    
    cmp al, 0       
    je return       
    jmp put_char    
put_char:           
    int 0x10        
    inc bx          
    jmp loop        
return:             
    popa            
    ret
```

Comment: `mov [bx], ax` is writing 2 bytes. So it's overwriting an extra byte that you probably did not intend to.

Comment: Note that you can generate digits in printing order (so you can loop forward instead of backward over the buffer) by rotating left, starting with the top nibble. 
 [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) shows how.  That makes it easier to use simpler indexing, fewer instructions in the loop.  Or since you're using 1 char at a time printing, you could just inline the printing into the digit loop.  Also, never `jcc` over a `jmp`, just `jng next` or fall through into the `add al, 'a'-10 - '0'`.

Comment: @Jester But why is it overwriting? I mean, both `bx` and `ax` are of the same size, everything should be okay, isn't it? Could you please elaborate on it.

Comment: It's a write to memory. The size of `bx` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jester could you please recommend me an article about registers or something, because I still don't quite understand how they work and why it's a write to memory :(

Comment: The brackets `[]` make it a memory reference. `mov bx, ax` would be a transfer between registers, `mov [bx], ax` is a write into memory at address `bx`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, this is pretty understandable, but why it gets overwritten?

Comment: An extra byte in memory gets overwritten. I haven't traced what exactly that causes in your code, but if it works with `al` then surely that is the problem.