# Print hexadecimal as ascii with NASM system call

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, system-calls

So I want to print out the ascii value of what is stored in an address with a system call.
Lets say i want to print the letter `Z` in hex this is `0x5a`, so lets say in my preamble there I have a pointer `ptr` point to a element of an array, I transfer the value at the address into `cl` by:

```
mov edx, ptr
mov cl, [edx]
```

Now lets say the value `0x5a` is in `cl`, how do I print this to STDOUT? I have tried (amoung other things):

```
mov eax, 4 ; SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, 1 ; STDOUT
;value to be prininted is in cl so it is in ecx
mov edx, 4 ; size of the item (tried 4 and 1)
int 80h ;interrupt
```

This prints absolutely nothing, what am I doing wrong? Do I need to declare something in .data / .bss?
I want it to print `Z`

Thanks

EDIT:

So I can print `Z` by declaring in `.data`:

```
num db 90
```

Then using `mov ecx, num` in the system call. but how can I take the hex value in the register and do the same?

Comment: The system call only takes pointers to data to print. So move the address of `ptr` to ecx with `mov ecx, ptr` and then tell it to print a single character so EDX should be 1. If you have a situation where you have a character in a register and want to display it, you have to write it to a memory location  (buffer) or even on the stack and then pass the address of that buffer in ECX to sys_write system call.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks it worked :)

Comment: Related: [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756)