# assembly iterating over bytes in register and doing something depending on values

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn some assembly, and following [this](https://omu.rce.so/gcc-2022/) guide.

I'm at exercise 3, which sounds like this:

Given n (stored in rdi) values stored in IN:

```
1. For each of BYTE value x taken from IN:
i. If x > 0x50, write x - 0x37 to OUT.
ii. Else, write x + 0x13 to OUT.
Hint: Note that values from 0x80 to 0xff are considered as negative values when they are a BYTE (because MSB is set). Make sure you use the unsigned versions of the jcc instructions.
To simplify your experience, r8 is initialised to 0x1000(IN), and r9 to 0x2000(OUT).
```

So my thought was that I should use the `loop` operator, and that I should use `jg` to test for a greater than comparison:

```
loop:
mov r10, r8
cmp r8, 0x50
jg great
not_great:
 sub r10, 0x37 
 mov r9, r10
great:
 add r10, 0x13
 mov r9, r10
end:
 hlt

jmp loop
```

There's probably a few issues here. But the first one is that I think I am just reading the same value from r8 again and agai, not iterating over them.
How do I actually iterate over them? so I don't hit the same value again and again?

Comment: To iterate you need to 1) increment `r8` in the loop and 2) dereference it, e.g. `cmp byte [r8], 0x50`. Also obviously having a `hlt` there will prohibit any iteration and the `jmp` should instead be a conditional that check whether you processed `n` items or not.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, but that's what I really can't figure out how to do. The dereferencing and so on

Comment: To iterate over the 8 bytes in a single qword register, you can `shr r10, 8` (or `ror r10, 8`) in a loop, and `cmp r10b, 0x50` or whatever else with the low byte of the register.  Or even extract it with `movzx eax, r10b`.  Like in this int->hex-string loop, where we want to loop over nibbles: [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) although that just copies the register and uses `and` to keep only the low 4 bits.

Comment: But I don't understand what it means to "write `x - 0x37` to `OUT`.  That sounds more like dealing with an array, unless they really mean just doing a `mov` store of different bytes to a specific memory address, like it was a device MMIO register so each write has some visible side-effect, not just the final value.

Comment: Probably they are talking about looping over arrays pointed-to by a register (like Jester said), not looping over the bytes literally *in* a single register like your question title said.