# Efficient transpose of 2D nibble matrix?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, simd, sse, avx2

Given a 2D 4x8 nibble matrix, represented as a 16-byte uint8_t array. For every pair of nibbles i, j, the byte is computed as so: `(j << 4) | i`.

For example, given the following matrix:

```
    0  1  2  3  3  7  1  9 
    4  5  6  7  4  1  6  15
    8  9  10 11 3  14 6  11
    12 13 14 15 8  10 7  4
```

represented as:

```
const uint8_t matrix[] = {
    0x10, 0x32, 0x73, 0x91,
    0x54, 0x76, 0x14, 0xf6,
    0x98, 0xba, 0xe3, 0xb6,
    0xdc, 0xfe, 0xa8, 0x47,
};
```

the desired array array would be:

```
const uint8_t result[] = {
    0x40, 0xc8, 0x51, 0xd9,
    0x62, 0xea, 0x73, 0xfb,
    0x43, 0x83, 0x17, 0xae,
    0x61, 0x76, 0xf9, 0x4b,
}
```

How to implement a function that achieves this most efficiently? Extensions up to AVX2 are fair game.

This is my C implementation so far, based on [Nibble shuffling with x64 SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71936833/nibble-shuffling-with-x64-simd). It splits the matrix into two 64bit inputs, unpacks the nibbles, shuffles them and re-packs them.

```c
__m128i unpack_nibbles(__m128i src) {
    __m128i nibbles_hi = _mm_srli_epi64(src, 4);

    //Interlave high nibbles with full nibbles [0000 hi, hi lo, ...] and clear high
    __m128i unpacked = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(src, nibbles_hi);
    return _mm_and_si128(unpacked, _mm_set1_epi8(0xf));
}

void transpose_4x8_nibbles(uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dst) {
    uint8_t *src_lo = src + 0x8;

    __m128i data_hi = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)src);
    __m128i data_lo = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)src_lo);

    data_hi = unpack_nibbles(data_hi);
    data_lo = unpack_nibbles(data_lo);

    //Transpose
    __m128i transpose_mask = _mm_setr_epi8(0, 0x8, 0x1, 0x9, 0x2, 0xa, 0x3, 0xb, 0x4, 0xc, 0x5, 0xd, 0x6, 0xe, 0x7, 0xf);
    data_hi = _mm_shuffle_epi8(data_hi, transpose_mask);
    data_lo = _mm_shuffle_epi8(data_lo, transpose_mask);

    //Pack nibbles
    __m128i pack_mask = _mm_set1_epi16(0x1001);
    data_hi = _mm_maddubs_epi16(data_hi, pack_mask);  //even bytes are multiplied by 0x10, odd bytes by 0x01
    data_lo = _mm_maddubs_epi16(data_lo, pack_mask);
    
    __m128i data = _mm_packus_epi16(data_hi, data_lo);
    data = _mm_shuffle_epi8(data, transpose_mask);
    
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*) dst, data);
}
```

Comment: @DavidRanieri: Pointer math on `void*` is a GNU extension (working like `char*`), but the question has since been edited to be portable.  We can delete these comments.

Comment: It feels like there *should* be a way to do this without unpack/repack.  Like shuffle bytes so the pairs you need are lined up, then vertical bit-blend with AND/ANDN/OR. (And then shuffle again to put the merged bytes where they belong).  But a blend doesn't work when we need the same nibble from both, e.g. the first byte of the output is `0x40` from `0x10` ; `0x54` ; the low nibble of each input byte (the starts of the first 2 rows).  Perhaps a left-shift of one input by 4 bits can work with 2 blends?

Comment: I suspect AVX-512 VBMI for vpmultishiftqb (parallel bitfield extract) could be helpful, perhaps along with 16-bit SIMD rotates (also AVX-512).   Or Galois Field GFNI for bit-shuffling (http://0x80.pl/articles/avx512-galois-field-for-bit-shuffling.html).  So if you're interested in also making a version for those ISA extensions, there might be something to gain.

Comment: I think I have a solution with 1 `pshufb`, 1 `pmaddwd` and 4 bitops (unfortunately, `pmaddwd` takes signed inputs). I'll write an answer later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets name the nibbles as follows (everything in little endian order):

```
X0 Y0 X1 Y1 X2 Y2 X3 Y3
Z0 W0 Z1 W1 Z2 W2 Z3 W3
X4 Y4 X5 Y5 X6 Y6 X7 Y7
Z4 W4 Z5 W5 Z6 W6 Z7 W7
```

After transposing we note that `X` nibbles stay in the low nibble, `W` nibbles stay in the high nibble, `Y` nibbles move from high to low and `Z` nibbles move from low to high:

```
X0 Z0 X4 Z4
Y0 W0 Y4 W4
X1 Z1 X5 Z5
Y1 W1 Y5 W5
X2 Z2 X6 Z6
Y2 W2 Y6 W6
X3 Z3 X7 Z7
Y3 W3 Y7 W7
```

That means the `X` and `W` nibbles can be placed correctly by a simple `pshufb`. The `Z` nibbles all need to be shifted up (or multiplied by `0x10`) the `Y` nibbles need to be shifted down (or multiplied as a `uint16` block by `0x1000` and taking the upper half of the result).

One block of `00 Z0 00 Z4 Y0 00 Y4 00` is actually like a 32bit integer and we can almost directly get this from `Z0 00 Z4 00` and `00 Y0 00 Y4` by a single `pmaddwd` instruction with `0x10` and `0x1000`:

```
00 Z0 00 Z4 Y0 00 Y4 00 = (00 Y0 00 Y4)* 0x1000 + (Z0 00 Z4 00) * 0x10
```

And these nibbles happen to be in the same bytes as `X0, X4` and `W0, W4` so only one `pshufb` is necessary to arrange the bytes accordingly, but unfortunately, if `Y4>7` we have a negative integer which requires masking away some bits again (at least, we can re-use the same mask).

Overall, this function should do the job:

```
void transpose_4x8_nibbles(uint8_t const *src, uint8_t *dst) {
    __m128i const input = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i const*)src);

    __m128i const shuff = _mm_shuffle_epi8(input, _mm_setr_epi8(0, 8, 4, 12, 1, 9, 5, 13, 2, 10, 6, 14, 3, 11, 7, 15));
    __m128i const mask = _mm_set1_epi32(0x0f0ff0f0);
    __m128i const XW = _mm_andnot_si128(mask, shuff);
    __m128i const YZ = _mm_and_si128(mask, shuff);
    __m128i const YZ_trans = _mm_madd_epi16(YZ, _mm_set1_epi32(0x00101000));
    __m128i const result = _mm_or_si128(XW, _mm_and_si128(mask, YZ_trans));

    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)dst, result);
}
```

Godbolt demo (only SSSE3 is required because of `pshufb`): https://godbolt.org/z/c43oTz43r