# Special purpose instructions to decompose bitfields

Tags: c, x86-64, simd, intrinsics

I have this bytecode that's encoded as 32bit instructions. Each opcode can have different formats for its operands. Normally, to decode each instruction, I do the usual C bit twiddling operations. But, I wondered if there are simd/intrinsic instructions that could help make decoding a bit faster. Decoding is not a bottle neck right now, as I'm at the beginning of the project, but I would want to try some special-purpose instruction to do it anyway, if they were available; even if just for the learning experience.

Are there such types of simd/intrinsics that are designed to decompose bitfields into constituent fields.

Comment: I assume you use x86-64 and not ARM or something else?

Comment: Correct. x86-64 only.

Comment: I know the Intel C/C++ compiler supports a bunch of intrinsics. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html

Comment: And GCC has a bunch of x86 built-in functions. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html

Comment: @IanAbbott GCC, Clang and MSVC also support the Intel intrinsics

Comment: `BEXTR` and `PEXT` from the BMI1 instructions?

Comment: Intrinsics are `_bextr_u32()` and `_pext_u32()`

Comment: You wrote "I have *this bytecode* that's encoded as 32bit instructions." Did you forget to show some code? Did you check that the code, generated by a optimizing compiler, would benefit from manual optimization?

Comment: Without a minimal example showing the decoding you need to do, it is not possible to give a precise answer.

Comment: @Shawn: Note that `bextr` on Intel is no faster than shift+AND or shift+`bzhi`, and you need a register with the two constants at the bottom so it's only good for multiple extracts of the same set of bitfields, not varying lengths.  And even then not saving uops vs. `rorx` + `and`, unless the mask wouldn't fit in a 32-bit immediate.  (AMD XOP had an immediate version of `bextr` on Bulldozer-family, but even Zen CPUs don't support that version.)

Comment: For fixed sequences of bitfield lengths, AVX-512 `vpmultishiftqb` is a parallel bitfield extract where each byte of the output grabs an unaligned 8-bit group from the qword it contains.  My answer on [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) shows an example of using it to unpack 4-bit fields to 8-bit as inputs to `vpshufb` or `vpermb`.

Comment: BMI2 `pext` and `pdep` are fast on Intel, and fast on Zen 3 and later.  (*Very* slow on earlier AMD, though).  With the right mask, `pdep` could unpack a couple bitfields to separate bytes or dword halves of the same register, ready to store two elements of an `int32_t` array for example if you want to unpack into memory instead of using right away.

Comment: Or if you do want to use right away, something like `pdep rax, rsi, rdi` can get fields to both the high and low halves of RAX (given a prepared mask for those two lengths packed at the bottom of RSI).   Then you can do `add ecx, eax` to add the low one to something, and `shr rax, 32` to isolate the high half, ready for something similar or even indexing memory (since it's now zero-extended to 64-bit).  pdep has 1/clock throughput on Intel, but shift or `rorx` can run in parallel with it, so 2 fields per pdep could be a slight win.

Comment: But that needs the fields at the bottom, unlike `pext` to extract one (or concatenate a couple) from anywhere in the register.  If you don't bottleneck on 1/clock `pext` / `pdep` throughput (or others that need port 1 on Intel, like `[lt]zcnt`/`popcnt` and `imul`, it's probably better to keep it simpler and minimize front-end uops.

Comment: So yeah, for decoding fields from fixed-width 32-bit instructions with a regular pattern, `pdep` or `pext` for at least one of the fields could work well, or `vpmultishiftqb` to decode many in parallel, perhaps with different vectors decoding different fields from the same sequence of upcoming 32-bit instructions.  Or `vpmovzxdq` to zero-extend each 32-bit instruction to 64-bit where you can pick apart the fields into bytes or dwords that can be semi-efficiently extracted back to integer regs by storing to an array and reloading.  (x86 `movzx` loads are efficient.)