# Assembly x86_64 print hex number digit per digit function not working

Tags: assembly, hex, x86-64, system-calls, low-level

I am trying to learn how to code in Assembly x86_64, but I'm getting some difficulties to make the syscall write work.

The idea here is to print the hex number, but digit per digit. I'm trying to iterate through the bytes, nibble by nibble and print the digit.

I think that I'm probably messing something with the addresses while trying to use the lea instructions, or maybe when trying to assign some values to the rsi register so it can have the value that I want to write in stdout.

The compilation doesn't fail, but only the print_newline function is writing the expected on the syscall.

```
section .data

newline_char: db 10
codes: db '0123456789abcdef'

section .text
global _start

print_newline:
    mov     rax, 1                  ; syscall write id
    mov     rdi, 1                  ; stdout file id
    mov     rsi, newline_char       ; data for the syscall write
    mov     rdx, 1                  ; number of bytes to write
    syscall
    ret

print_hex:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdx, 1
    mov     rcx, 64                 ; rax shift

iterate:
    push    rax                     ; push rax initial value to stack
    sub     rcx, 4
    sar     rax, cl                 ; shift for 60, 56, 52, ..., 4, 0
                                    ; cl is the lower part of rcx
    and     rax, 0xf                ; clear all the bits, except the 4 less significative
    lea     rsi, [codes + rax]      ; get one hex digit code

    mov     rax, 1
    push    rcx                     ; syscal will change rcx, so push it to the stack
    syscall                         ; rax = 1, syscall write
                                    ; rdi = 1, stdout files
                                    ; rsi = adress of one char

    pop     rcx
    pop     rax
    test    rcx, rcx                ; rcx = 0 when all the digits are shown
    jnz     iterate

    ret

_start:
    mov     rdi, 0x1122334455667788
    call    print_hex
    call    print_newline

    mov     rax, 60
    xor     rdi, rdi
    syscall
```

Comment: Use `strace ./a.out` to trace your system calls.  Looks like you're calling `write(EDI, RSI, RDX)` with EDI=`0x55667788` so it should return `-EBADF`.  Also, `print_hex` doesn't even read the input RDI.  See [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) for working code that creates a string in a buffer instead of inefficiently writing one character at a time.  Single-step debugging with GDB to verify the comments at the `syscall` would be another way to make the problem easy to find.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate of a debugging question because it's a simple problem similar to a typo: you just forgot to set up the system call args and read your function arg.  (And yes, stack overflow has typo as a close reason, because the actual problem isn't related to the task you were trying to solve so future readers with the same problem won't find it.)