# Nasm: Problem in print Hex info from BMP image

Tags: assembly, nasm, hexdump

My goal with this code is, like Hexdump, print the hexadecimal information of the BMP image given as an argument by the terminal. The problem is that whenever I run the program I receive `BM_` instead of the image's hexadecimal information. From my experience with the functions, I believe that the problem is found in the `openAndReadBMPFile` function or in the code before calling the `printStr` function and after calling the `openAndReadBMPFile` function.

```
section .data

    LF equ 10 
    NULL equ 0 
    TRUE equ 1
    FALSE equ 0
    EXIT_SUCCESS equ 0 
    STDIN equ 0 
    STDOUT equ 1 
    STDERR equ 2 
    SYS_read equ 0 
    SYS_write equ 1 
    SYS_open equ 2 
    SYS_close equ 3 
    SYS_fork equ 57 
    SYS_exit equ 60 
    SYS_creat equ 85 
    SYS_time equ 201 
    O_CREAT equ 0x40
    O_TRUNC equ 0x200
    O_APPEND equ 0x400
    O_RDONLY equ 000000q 
    O_WRONLY equ 000001q 
    O_RDWR equ 000002q 
    S_IRUSR equ 00400q
    S_IWUSR equ 00200q
    S_IXUSR equ 00100q

    BUFF_SIZE equ 255 
    newLine db LF, NULL 

    bmpFileDesc         dq  0
    sgFileDesc         dq  0
    MAX_IMG_SIZE        equ 1048576

    errMsgOpenBmp       db "Erro ao abrir o BMP", LF, NULL
    errImgRead          db "Erro ao ler o BMP", LF, NULL


section .bss

    readImgBuffer: resb MAX_IMG_SIZE 


section .text


printStr:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rbx
    mov rbx, rdi
    mov rdx, 0   
    
strCountLoop:
    cmp byte [rbx], NULL
    je strCountDone
    inc rdx
    inc rbx
    jmp strCountLoop   
    
strCountDone:
    cmp rdx, 0
    je prtDone
    mov rax, SYS_write
    mov rsi, rdi
    mov rdi, STDOUT 
    syscall     
    
prtDone:
    pop rbx
    pop rbp
    ret
        
printStrLn:
    call printStr
    mov rdi, newLine
    call printStr
    ret


errorOnOpenBmp:
    mov rdi, errMsgOpenBmp
    call printStr
    call terminate
    
errorOnRead:
    mov rdi, errMsgRead
    call printStr
    call terminate


openAndReadBMPFile: 

    push rsi 
    mov rax, SYS_open 
    mov rsi, O_RDONLY 
    syscall 
    cmp rax, 0
    jl errorOnOpenBmp
    mov [bmpFileDesc], rax 
    mov rax, SYS_read

    mov rdi, [bmpFileDesc]
    pop rsi 
    mov rsi, readImgBuffer
    mov rdx, MAX_IMG_SIZE

    syscall
    cmp rax, 0
    jl errorOnRead
    push rax 
    mov rax, SYS_close
    mov rdi, qword [bmpFileDesc]
    syscall
    pop rax
    ret



global _start 
_start: 

mov rdi, [rsp + 16]
call openAndReadBMPFile

mov rsi, readImgBuffer
mov byte [rsi+rax], NULL
mov rdi, readImgBuffer
call printStr

terminate:
    mov rax, SYS_exit
    mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
    syscall
```

Comment: It's unclear why you expect the binary bmp data to be a hex dump string. You are just printing the raw content of the file up to the first zero byte which is the `BM` signature probably followed by some non-printable bytes. You will need to do the conversion to hex dump yourself and also not stop at the first zero.

Comment: Use [How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756) to make ASCII text with a hex-digit representation of your binary data.  Binary data is binary, not already a string of ASCII characters.  That's why `hexdump -C` is different from `cat`.