# Are unsigned and signed binary conversions to hexadecimal the same?

Tags: math, assembly, binary, hex

Does this process change if the binary is signed, or do we convert the string into hexadecimal using the same method?

Taking the unsigned binary value `1111 0110`, when converting it into hexadecimal, we get the value `F6`. To convert back, we simply take each hex digit and convert it into its binary value. So `F` (which is decimal 15) is `1111`, and `6` is `0110`.

If the string "1111 0110" were signed, would the value of this string still be `F6`?

Comment: What is "_if the binary is signed_"/"_if the string 1111 0110 were signed_" supposed to mean? You are talking about values, not types. So it isn't clear what "signed" is supposed to mean in your context.

Comment: "_The leading one in a binary string can be used to represent whether or not a number is positive or not._": OK, but then you are talking about bit representations of a given integer type and not an integer value. The binary value `1111 0110` is just the decimal value `246`. That has nothing to do with how the value is represented. Representations can be done in many different ways and depend on the size of the type as well.

Comment: Depends on what you are asking and I suspect that your question doesn't actually reflect what you intent to ask. Again, the value `1111 0110`, interpreted by usual mathematical notation, is not a signed number (as it lacks a `-` in front) and so your question asking what happens if it were signed doesn't make sense.

Comment: *A zero is positive* - The usual technical terminology is that a zero is "non-negative", but also not positive.  For two's complement bit-patterns, the MSB tells you whether it's negative or non-negative.

Answer (score 4):

Usually when converting to hex, we just care about the bit-pattern, not the value represented by a 2's complement interpretation of those bits.  **By convention, readers expect that hex or binary is for bit-patterns rather than values,** like a hex-dump of what's actually there rather than some meaning for the bits.

So yes, `1111 0110` is `0xF6`.   Both are ways to express the bit-pattern for an 8-bit 2's complement representation of `-10`, or for unsigned `246`.

But you *could* print it as `-0xa` (signed base 16) just like you could print it as `-10` (signed base 10) for an 8-bit 2's complement interpretation.

To implement this, you'd do `if (val<0) { *buf++ = '-'; val = 0U - val; }` at the start then carry on to convert the unsigned absolute value (magnitude) of the number into the rest of your output buffer, like for base 10.

(Except this is hex so we can get the leading digits first, by shifting or rotating.  *[How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823756/how-to-convert-a-binary-integer-number-to-a-hex-string)*.  Unless we want to skip leading zeros then it would be more convenient to start with the lowest 4-bit group and convert backwards into a buffer.  In that case, just remember the original input and Tack on a `-` to the front after shifting out all the non-zero bits if the original input had been negative.)

> A zero is positive

The usual technical terminology is that a zero is "non-negative", but also not positive.  For two's complement bit-patterns, the MSB tells you whether it's negative or non-negative.

In assembly on machines with a flags register, most have a flag that's set according to the MSB, usually called the sign flag.  It tells you whether the number was negative or not.  To see if a number was positive, you also need the zero flag to be cleared, like x86 `jg` jumps if `SF=OF && ZF=0`.  In a compare against zero like `test al,al`, the signed Overflow flag will be zero.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc

Comment: "*It tells you whether the number was negative or not*" — in case the intent is to interpret as signed (and if that is not the intent, then the SF being set/cleared is a harmless side effect).  (And then there's overflow..)

Answer (score 3):

We use hex on machines that have integers that are multiples of 8 bits, because it results in an exact number of hex digits.

So, when we write 0xF6, that usually means an 8-bit value.  We cannot tell if that 8-bit value is signed or unsigned, if signed it would be negative b/c the MSB is set.  When we write 0xFFF6 that usually means a 16-bit value, and similarly we do not know if it is signed (and hence negative) or unsigned.

If we write fewer digits, like 0xF we still don't know for sure but the presumption would be that this is a positive value, 15<sub>10</sub>, since it is incomplete in digits for even a byte size, though it could be negative if it is a signed 4-bit value.

You can trim leading zeros, though this can add to uncertainty.  For example, a 32-bit number whose value is 65535 is 0x0000FFFF, and this is clearly a positive number whether signed or unsigned, but with leading zeros trimmed, it is 0xFFFF, which could be either positive if unsigned or negative if signed.

Trimming leading 1's is also possible, but less common.

When debugging assembly language, the debugger doesn't know if registers' values are signed or unsigned, so often a full 32- or 64-bit hex representation is used including all the leading zeros.

> Are unsigned and signed binary conversions to hexadecimal the same?

Yes.

> If the string "1111 0110" were signed, would the value of this string still be F6?

Yes.  (Though it may be more appropriate to have 0xFFF6, or 0xFFFFFFF6 in some contexts to emphasize the negative nature.)

Here we can see that F6 is hex.  But without further context, if it were 76 we wouldn't necessarily even be able to tell the number base so that is perhaps better written 0x76 or 76h or maybe 76<sub>16</sub>.

It also gets confusing if we speak to numbers that are not multiples of 4 (or 8) bits.  So, in the binary string "111 0110", we would say that is 0x76, but now this can translate to the binary string "0111 0110", and this would imply a positive value.

It thus is best to know qualities like number of bits and numeric type (signed vs. unsigned) from external metadata beyond the bit pattern — such as declared types of variables in C or other languages, file formats or other specifications that define bit fields, statements made in the text of exam problems, etc..

Comment: Hex works nicely on machines with multiples of 4 bits.  e.g. on CPUs with 12-bit words or characters like PDP-8. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-bit_computing . Although 12 is also a multiple of 3 so octal worked well without any partial digits, and was popular on such machines.  (Your first sentence says multiples of 8)

Answer (score 1):

The numerical value of a binary string is always the same. However, we can interpret it in a different way, which will make it represent a different number. So the bit string `1001` has the numerical value `9`. Now, if the first bit of the string is viewed as its sign, with `1` being `-` and `0` being `+`, then `1001` is interpreted as `-1`. If the used interpretation is [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), then `1001` is `-7`.
If I understood the underlying question correctly, that is,
Does the trick to convert binary into hexadecimal by converting each group of 4 binary digits into one hexadecimal digit works even when the binary is interpreted as a signed one under some convention ?
The answer is no, but in some cases you can adapt this trick to the representation.
Not a proof, but to help convince yourself you can try with the example above :
if I interpret `1001` as `-001`, I have `1001 = -1`.  Taking `1001` as `-001` = `-0001`, we easily convert `0001` to `0x1` ( here I use `0x` to denote that 1 is in hexadecimal) and so with a little more work to adapt to the binary interpretation, it works.

If I have a binary string interpreted with the [IEEE754 convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), I cannot apply this at all since it is a totally different interpretation of the values of each bit of the string.

With the two's complement interpretation, I can follow the algorithm to make the string interpretation adjusted to its binary value and then convert it to hex with the trick.

The proper way to answer your question would be to explain why this trick works, but for that you can just look [at this question on the math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597019/in-plain-english-why-does-conversion-from-hexadecimal-to-binary-work-so-cleanly)

Comment: 4-bit 2's complement `1001` is `-0111` (signed binary), or `-7` decimal.  It's 1 higher than the most-negative value, MSB set rest clear = `-8`.  Your `-0001` interpretation would be correct for sign/magnitude where `-x` just flips the sign bit.

Comment: Also, unsigned `0b1001` is `9`.

Comment: you are totally right I should not be doing additions in my head this late